# Different posts_per_page depending on page number

Tags: php, wordpress

"CODE A" below is used to exclude categories. But I also want to accomplish this:

If is page 1-3, display 8 posts
If is page 4 or more, display 9 posts

How to accomplish this? And how can this be added into "CODE A" ?

.
**CODE A**

```
function exclude_categories($query){  
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {  
    $query->set( 'category__not_in', array(60, 61) );  
    }  
}  
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_categories' );
```

Comment: I think the global __$paged__ could be the right for this accomplish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not able to test it yet, but this could work

```
function exclude_categories($query){    
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 

    if ( $paged < 4 ) :
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 8 );
    else :
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 9 );
    endif;

    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {  
    $query->set( 'category__not_in', array(60, 61) );  
    }  
}  
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_categories' );
```

Perhaps you have to replace

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
```

with

```
global $paged; 
$paged = ( is_int($paged) && $paged !== 0 ) ? $paged : 1;
```