# Enforcing posts per page specified in WordPress settings

Tags: php, wordpress

Problem is that despite specifying "posts per page" to be 9 in WordPress settings area,
WordPress is NOT counting the post that is injected by the awesome plugin below, 
therefore my website will display a total of 10 posts (9 posts plus 1 injected post).
How can I make WordPress count the injected post?

-My posts are displayed in a 3 column layout.
-I am using the plugin below to inject a post from a specific category called "sponsor".
-In WordPress admin area > Settings > Reading > I set "posts per page" to be 9.

This matters because if I have 2 posts in the category "sponsor" that I want to inject,
then page 1 will display the first sponsored post,
and page 2 will display the second sponsored post,
but page 3 and beyond will display nothing (which is correct because there are no more "sponsor" posts)
so the layout will show empty space.

.
**Workaround that did not work**

Using $paged and changing posts_per_page for $paged < 3 caused the plugin to NOT properly work. 
It would not display injected post for page 2. 
[See $paged code here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26571578/different-posts-per-page-depending-on-page-number)

.
**Problem: Need WordPress to count the post (injected by the plugin)**

X represents my posts
O represents sponsored posts injected by the plugin
If I have 2 posts in "sponsor" category, page 3 and beyond will not have a "sponsor" post to inject so will have empty space:

```
Page 1    Page 2     Page 3  

X X X      X X X      X X X  
X X X      X X X      X X X  
X O X      X O X      X X
```

**Plugin**

[Click Here](https://gist.github.com/birgire/439e36a6b08f1159f653) for the Github plugin code.